# ServiceStack global request redirect

Tags: c#, redirect, servicestack, swagger-ui

I'm trying to get a redirect to work to use /docs instead of /swagger-ui.  I implemented the handler (basically copied from [OpenApiFeature.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi/OpenApiFeature.cs)) to catch the /docs path and server /swagger-ui content, but it only works with /docs/, not /docs.  With /docs, all the css and js files resolve to the root instead of the /docs folder (host/blah.js instead of host/docs/blah.js):

```
appHost.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) =>
{
    IVirtualFile indexFile = null;

    switch (pathInfo.ToLower())
    {
        case "/docs":
        case "/docs/":
        case "/docs/default.html":
            indexFile = appHost.VirtualFileSources.GetFile("/swagger-ui/index.html");
            break;
        default:
            indexFile = null;
            break;
    }

    if (indexFile != null)
    {
        var html = indexFile.ReadAllText();

        return new CustomResponseHandler((req, res) =>
        {
            res.ContentType = MimeTypes.Html;
            return html;
        });
    }
    return pathInfo.StartsWithIgnoreCase("/docs") ? new StaticFileHandler(pathInfo.ReplaceFirst("/docs", "/swagger-ui")) : null;
});
```

To fix this, I figured I could just redirect /docs to /docs/:

```
        case "/docs":
        return new RedirectHttpHandler() {RelativeUrl = "/docs/"};
```

The problem with that is it also downgrades the connection from https to http somehow.  Since it's a relative redirect, I'm not sure what's going on there.  Is there a better way to implement this?  To make it worse, it works on my local dev machine, but not our test environment.  Both run stand-alone SS.  Clearly there's some different setting, but I can't really imagine what would cause that.

I'm probably missing something dumb, but I just can't find it.  Is there a more recent setting to make this easier out-of-the-box?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack will rewrite the url to include `http` or `https` depending on the incoming request which you can force to use `https` links by setting `Config.UseHttpsLinks=true`, also the easiest way to add a redirect is to add it to [Config.RedirectPaths](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.14#redirect-paths), together this looks like:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    UseHttpsLinks = true,
    RedirectPaths = {
        { "/docs", "/swagger-ui/" },
    }
});
```

Note: if you're using a proxy that's terminating the https SSL connection it should ideally be configured to set the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` HTTP Request Header so downstream App servers can determine whether the original request was sent over `https`.